# Use fread to subset rows

Tags: r, fread

I have a very large dataset where I want to susbet rows and columns in fread itself. I used the following code

```
  dat <- na.omit(fread(text = "C:/data.txt", header = FALSE, skip = 100,
                     fill = T, select = c(1, 2, 3),
                     col.names = c("A", "B", "C"),
                     na.strings = "#"))
```

The 'data.txt' file has 30 columns and a million rows. I have selected the first 3 columns in the fread function and omitted NA rows. The first column is time. I want to include a subset() in fread that reads only the rows where time > 25. Is this possible? I would prefer not to read all the rows and subset later

Comment: This doesn't seem to be possible - you can skip a designated number of rows, but cannot define indices by which to read. A million rows does not sound too bad though, so I would think you could read this in completely and then filter.

Comment: You could first [awk](https://www.howtogeek.com/562941/how-to-use-the-awk-command-on-linux/) and then `fread` it.

Answer (score 0):

For handling this with just R, you could use the `vroom` library to lazy load your data and then filter them so you can keep in memory only the subset that you need.

See here for more
https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/05/vroom-1-0-0/

Don't know the format of your data but the script would go like this

```
library(dplyr)
library(vroom)

dat <- vroom("C:/data.txt", skip = 100, na = "#") #lazy loads your entire dataset

#dat_sub stores the subset in memory

dat_sub <- dat |> 
             select(yourcols) |> # select the columns you want
             filter(time > 25) #filter time column
```